# Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I have following app.js file for angular, and i want to add a response interceptor but when i add response interceptor it throws me an error on console

> Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr]

Below is the file

```
(function () {
        "use strict";

        angular.module("builder").config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider", "$provide","$httpProvider",
                function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider, $provide, $httpProvider) {

                    $httpProvider.responseInterceptors.push('responseObserver');
    }]).factory('responseObserver',
                function responseObserver($q, $window) {
            return function (promise) {
                return promise.then(function (successResponse) {
                    return successResponse;
                }, function (errorResponse) {

                switch (errorResponse.status) {
                case 401:
                    $window.location = $window.location;
                    break;
                case 403:
                    $window.location = './403.html';
                    break;
                  case 500:
                    $window.location = './500.html';
               }

               return $q.reject(errorResponse);
              });
            };
        });
    }());
```

Can anyone guide me what is causing this issue.

Comment: So if you click on the angular error links and keep drilling down on each page that's loaded you'll get to the culprit. My guess is that `$q` or `$window` cannot be found when trying to inject into the `factory`.

Answer (score 0):

You didn't define the angular module 'builder' anywhere. The following format (which your file uses):

```
angular.module("builder")
```

means, "use the angular module 'builder' which I have already defined."

The following format:

```
angular.module("builder",[])
```

means, "create the angular module 'builder' right here and now (and eliminate any previous one)".

You *can* create and use at the same time as:

```
angular.module("builder",[]).config(....
```

but you must define it somewhere at least once.

Comment: OK, so that isn't it, although it would give that error. You have a `modulerr`. You sure the other file is called, and is called first?

Comment: Yes i am sure on that

Comment: Then can you put up more code, and more of the error message? A plunkr or jsfiddle would be very helpful

Answer (score 0):

Your factory should be changed like below:

```
.factor('responseObserver', '$window', function responseObserver($window, $q){

});
```

notice the way I injected `$window`. You have to annotate the $window, so that injector can recognize the functions/directives/services to be injected.

Comment: You don't. It recognizes it from the name of the argument. You only need the annotation if you will minify, and even then, `ng-annotate` will do it for you. In any case, it would have to be in an array, and all of the arguments would have to match.

Comment: @ditch Well, this is something I wasn't aware of. Thanks for letting me know. :)